# Auto-renewable subscription with Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, subscription

I'm trying to implement a subscription model in my app writen in Objective-C. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a full tutorial and a sample code. I tried to implement Swift codes but it doesn't work properly.
Any help would be great.

Comment: check https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit